# how to get my android USSD program to work

Tags: android

am building a simple dialler to help me check my account balance but for some unknown reasons am getting some errors, i have a button on my xml which i have set its onclick element to sendMessage1 , but am getting error on my code with the phoneNum[1] telling me cannot reslove symbol phoneNum[1]. this is my code

```
/**Called when the user clicks the Send button */

public void sendMessage1(View view){
    //example phoneNum[1] = "*556";
    String encodedHarsh = Uri.encode("#");
    startActivity(new Intent
            ("android.intent.action.DIAL",
                    Uri.parse("tel:"+ phoneNum[1]+ encodedHarsh)));
    //Do something in response to button
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_mtn);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_mtn, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: What's `phonenum[1]`?

Comment: just a term I used to define the ussd code *556. is there something wrong with it ? can u write a sample code to make it easier

Comment: I don't know what exactly you want to do

Comment: Just try this code : `String encodedHarsh = "*" + "556" + Uri.encode("#");
startActivity(new Intent("android.intent.action.CALL", Uri.parse("tel:" + encodedHarsh)));`

Comment: I want the ussd code *556# to be dialed when my button is clicked

Comment: @skizo I will try that and get back to u

Comment: Dont forget to add user permisions in manifest

Comment: it worked fine. thanks

Comment: Ive added the same as an answer so you can mark this question as a solved :) happy coding

Comment: @skizo is the any way i can reach u privately so i can get some more help, since stackoverflow wont let me post more questions

Comment: You can ask question and give me the link so I'll help you :) But if I answered your question you *must* accept it as a correct. And feel free to give me the link and I'll try my best to give you a correct answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do it doing this :

```
String encodedHarsh = "*" + "556" + Uri.encode("#");
startActivity(new Intent("android.intent.action.CALL", Uri.parse("tel:" + encodedHarsh)));
```

*Note, don't forget to add `uses-permisions` on manifest*